# Why does shapefile resolution change in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, resolution

When I work in ArcGIS Pro the shapefile visualizes correctly in the map.

However, when I upload the same shapefile as a compressed ZIP file to ArcGIS Online and then visualize it in Map Viever the image resolution greatly reduces.

**Even when I generate the ZIP file with 0% compression factor (only storage), the problem remains.**

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try uploading it not in a zip file? SO share a web layer in ArcPro.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I have already tried that, publishing from ArcPro as a web layer and the problem remains. :(

Comment: Shapefiles are vector datasets, and vector data is resolution independent by definition.  So there is something else odd going on with that layer.